# Java ImagIO.write() changes quality during save

Tags: java, image, graphics, save

I am writing an image library for fun and i came across a problem that i can't seem to solve. The class is pretty simple: take a picture, process it, display it through JFrame, and finally save it as a BufferedImage (javax.imageio.ImageIO). Here is what my picture looks like through the JFrame (this is my ColorEnhance class... on the Drustan nebula):

[image: The image as seen from the JFrame]

Here is what the saved version (a png, but all types ImageIO.write() supports look the same):

[image: The image as seen after it has been saved]

I'm not sure where the change occurs, but when I run this through my blur method entire lines appear from nothing in the png... Anyways, here is some code:

```
public void writeToFile(BufferedImage finalPic, String nameToAppend)
{
    String temp=fileName.replace(".", nameToAppend+".");
    String ext=fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf(".")+1);
    File file=new File(temp);
    try
    {
        ImageIO.write(finalPic, ext.toUpperCase(), file);
        System.out.println("Successfully saved to: "+temp);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.getMessage(); }
}

public void displayImage(String titleName)
{
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(newPic);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(titleName);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    label.setIcon(icon);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT+22);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

One last thing is that the save works for some processing classes better than others, if you need to see any more code just ask, thanks

Comment: I have increased your rep, post the necessary images for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Those code snippets do not even indicate what image type is being used!  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Ok, Thanks Andrew, i guess i should have made it more clear that I exhausted all the image types that ImageIO.write() supports with the same results every time. I neglected to post the rest of the code because i know that the error lies somewhere in the ImageIO or BufferedImage interaction (I'm not too familiar with them). If a fix can't be found, i can live with it and spaghetti patch my way around it somehow... Bottom line: is there some way that i can make my saved file look exactly the same as the output through the JFrame?

Comment: Have you tried to save the image directly without applying any filters ? I believe that `ImageIO` is not the cause, it must be your faulty `ImageFilter`

Comment: Yes, and does work fine. As for my filter (class ColorEnhance), it looks great in the JFrame, so i can only assume it works correctly. If i print out the RGB's of my BufferedImage, eyeballing it, it seems to match more correctly with the JFrame than the png. That's all i know.

Comment: Is there just some way that i can take the colors and paint them into a picture and export that? Even if it makes runtime longer i would be happier with that than what i have now.

Comment: Have you tried saving the image using `ImageIO.write(finalPic, "PNG", new File("/tmp/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png"));`
And I'd suggest start by doing so RIGHT after reading the image from disk. Same as ExtremeCoders I strongly doupt that ImageIO.write() is the root of the problem - but well you never know.

Comment: Could it be that you are applying your filter multiple times somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `PNGImageEncoder` from [Apache XML Graphics Commons](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/commons/download.html):

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
PNGImageEncoder encoder = new PNGImageEncoder(new FileOutputStream("file.png"), null);
encoder.encode((RenderedImage) image);
```